# brute-force factors of numbers on my computer at home?

Tags: rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis

I am currently researching RSA crypto and brute-forcing keys and read about the factoring-problem. There is an increasing difficulty with factorizing numbers of an increasing value, especially when it comes to primes, and this is one of the reasons to why RSA keys are impossible to brute-force.

Not completely unrelated, I was just wondering if I could brute-force factors of specific numbers using my regular computer that I have for personal use. I would like to measure the time it takes to facorize the numbers and how time changes as the numbers grow. Is there a program to download which can do so (facotrize the numbers that is, not neccesary with the time measuring part)? If not then why is it not possible?

Comment: In principle you can do it with two for/next loops, but that's - uh - somewhat non-optimal :) Note that asking for references to applications is made *explicitly* off topic.

Comment: There are lots of tools out there for factoring integers, such as GGNFS, MSIEVE, and YAFU. Unfortunately none of them are the "click and run" type programs. They require a bit of work to get going.

Comment: I'd actually suggest you to learn some programming basics. Writing a small script that does what you described is pretty trivial once you know the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the paper [Factoring as a Service](https://ia.cr/2015/1000) for what you can do using the cloud. In the introduction on page 2 they write [where](https://github.com/eniac/faas) you can find their Software.